# Configurable TFS 2010 CI Builds

Tags: build, continuous-integration

I am planning to create build definitions for one of our projects for CI automated builds. We have 2 environments - QA and Live and the same application will be running in 3 countries. So we have to have a set of QA and Live build folders for each country.

While publishing the application to each country, we used to manually update the app.config file in the project (have 1 for each country) and deploy to the country specific location. Could this be achieved in the automated builds in some way that for each checkin, a build 
gets generated an published to the QA environment of each country by picking the appropriate config file?

Thanks in Advance,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

You can have a different configuration for each country + environment combination (CI-UK, CI-US, QA-UK, QA-US); then in the CI build definition you specify to build all CI configurations for each country (CI-UK and CI-US).
For generating the specific configurations you should use the [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) Visual Studio add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Through [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/), on Codeplex, you can manipulate the config files to deploy and configure a specific environment.